# Recover Notifications on Android 10

Tags: notifications, restore, android-10, history

Is there a way to recover a dismissed notification from an App? Using a 3rd party App usually requires future history since the notification was dismissed before the installation.

Possibly in a cache or history setting but Android 10 doesn't have Notification History in Settings.

Comment: The last part of the answer should help